# Configuring a CMake project with dependencies on multiple other CMAKE projects

Tags: c++, build, cmake

I have a CMAKE project that depends on other projects built with CMAKE. These are : glfw, oglplus, portaudio etc.

How should I set up my project to work well in a cross platform fashion? What is the recommended way to go about it?  I have been trying to read the CMAKE documentation but could only find examples to simple scenarios.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Just add the dependencies to your project README and expect the user stored them (already compiled) in system scope.
- Add CMake options to request the path to dependency files.
- Use [add_subdirectory](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#command:add_subdirectory) to chain your project with dependencies.